# How to process files in FastAPI from multiple clients without saving the files to disk

Tags: python, file-upload, classification, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to create an API that receives small audio files from a mobile app. In this API I do processing of the signal and I am able to return a response after classifying that sound. The final goal is to send the classification back to the user.

**Here's what I am doing so far:**

```
@app.post("/predict")

def predict(file: UploadFile = File(...)):   # Upload the wav audio sent from the mobile app user

 with open(name_file, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)  #creating a file with the received audio data
...

prev= test.my_classification_module(name_file) #some processing and the goal response in PREV variable
```

In `my_classification_module()`, I have this :

```py
X, sr = librosa.load(sound_file)
```

I want to avoid creating a file to be classified with `librosa`. I would like to do this with a temporary file, without using memory unecessarily and to avoid the overlap of files when the app is used by multiple users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function supports a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object, you could use the `.file` attribute of `UploadFile`, e.g., `file.file` (which is a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) instance), or if your function requires the file in `bytes` format, use the `.read()` *async* method (see the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile)). If you wish to keep your route defined with `def` instead of `async def` (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more info on `def` vs `async def`), you could use the `.read()` method of the [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object directly, e.g., `file.file.read()`.

#### Update - How to resolve `File contains data in an unknown format` error

1. Make sure the audio file is not corrupted. If, let's say, you saved it and opened it with a media player, would the sound file play?
2. Make sure you have the latest version of `librosa` module installed.
3. Try installing `ffmpeg` and adding it to the system path, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496551).
4. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429342) and in the
   [documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html#read-file-like-objects), `librosa.load()` can take a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object as an alternative to a file path - thus, using `file.file` or `file.file._file` should normally be fine (as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), `_file` attribute is either an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) object...).

   However, as described in the documentation [here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html#read-specific-formats) and [here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html#read-file-like-objects), as well as in this [github discussion](https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile/issues/302), you could also use the [soundfile](https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile) module to read audio from [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) objects. Example:

   ```py
   import soundfile as sf 
   data, samplerate = sf.read(file.file)
   ```
5. You could also write the file `contents` of the uploaded file to a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) stream, and then pass it to either `sf.read()` or `librosa.load()`:

   ```py
   from io import BytesIO
   contents = file.file.read()
   buffer = BytesIO(contents)
   data, samplerate = librosa.load(buffer)  # ussing librosa module
   #data, samplerate = sf.read(buffer)      # using soundfile module
   buffer.close()
   ```
6. Another option would be to save the file `contents` to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which "has a visible name in the file system" that "can be used to open the file". Once you are done with it, you can manually delete it using the `remove()` or `unlink()` method.

   ```py
   from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
   import os
   contents = file.file.read()
   temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
   try:
       with temp as f:
           f.write(contents);
       data, samplerate = librosa.load(temp.name)   # ussing librosa module
       #data, samplerate = sf.read(temp.name)       # using soundfile module
   except Exception:
       return {"message": "There was an error processing the file"}
   finally:
       #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
       os.remove(temp.name)
   ```

Comment: using .file method I get this error: File contains data in an unknown format

Comment: I am using librosa.load(soundfile) the file is used there and gets confused if I dont save it first with the name "file.wav"... I edited my question

Comment: not really.. it gives me the same wrror when i use the read and i have been trying with named tempfiles and also it is not possible... the audios are no corrupted

Comment: yes this is right, the last option worked, thanks so much! I want to put this as the right answear