# Uploading file to Anonfiles using anonfile module and FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, dropzone

I am currently creating a website where the user sends the file and gets uploaded to anonfile website (I am using [anofile python module](https://github.com/nstrydom2/anonfile-api)). Before anonfile module, I was using mediafire module but it didn't work with video files so I moved to anonfile modul.

Here is the code:

app.py

```py
from typing import List
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Request, UploadFile
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from anonfile import AnonFile

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates/")

def direct_link_anon(link):
  down_link1 = link
  r1 = requests.get(down_link1)
  soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "html.parser")
  a_href1 = soup1.find("a", {"id": "download-url"}).get("href")
  a1 = str(a_href1)
  print(a1)
  return a1

@app.post("/")
async def create_upload_files(uploaded_files: list[UploadFile]):
    for files in uploaded_files:
        anon = AnonFile()
        upload = anon.upload(files.file)
        link = upload.url.geturl()
        result=direct_link_anon(link)
        download = "Download"
    return {'download': download,'result': result}


@app.get("/")
async def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html',context={'request': request})


uvicorn.run(app)
```

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>file upload</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" class="dropzone" id="my-great-dropzone">
    </form>
    <a id="download-link" href=""></a>
    <script>
        Dropzone.options.myGreatDropzone = { // camelized version of the `id`
            paramName: "uploaded_files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 20000, // MB
            uploadMultiple: false,
            maxFiles: 1,
            maxFilesize: 1000000000,
            init: function() {
                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                        this.removeAllFiles();
                        this.addFile(file);
                });
            } ,
            chunking: true,
            createImageThumbnails: true,
            success: function(file, response){
                var abc = response['result'];
                document.getElementById('download-link').innerHTML = '<a href="' + abc + '">Download</a>';
            }
        };
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The **error**:

```
files.file is not a directory
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package your are using to upload the file doesn't seem to support passing a [`file-like`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object (which is the result of calling the `.file` attribute of the [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) object). As can been in the source code [here](https://github.com/nstrydom2/anonfile-api/blob/9d85a80040fe323545ed1a91d31b4caa19964899/src/anonfile/anonfile.py#L267), the `upload` function instead accepts a `path` to the file in either `str` or `Path` format.

Hence, you can either save the file to a local directory on your disk and then pass the filepath to the `upload` function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804), or save the file to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which unlike [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) that `UploadFile` provides (using the `.file` attribute), "has a visible name in the file system"—which you can get using the `.name` attribute—and "can be used to open the file". Related answers with examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886990/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766160/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804), as well as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804).