# Upload file and convert it to BytesIO using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, temporary-files, pdfminer

I was using streamlit for my api before and after file was submitted I got BytesIO, which I could successfully run in my python script (PDFMiner, tessseract-ocr, etc)
I, however, had to switch to FastAPI and lost in terms of what data type I am receiving

```py
@app.post("/file_upload", response_model=ResponseModel)
async def upload(pdf: UploadFile = File(...)) -> ResponseModel:
    if pdf is not None:
        text = TextExtraction.extract_text(pdf)
```

TextExtraction:

```py
ef extract_text(pdf):
    try:
        text = extract_text(pdf.file)
        text = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 :,@$€+.\n-()-]+', '', text)
        texts = texts + '\n' + text
    except:
        pass
```

I know how to make script work with BytesIO, but UploadFile class is new to me and I am confused, having found nothing of much help online.
Can someone either help me convert TempFile to bytesIO or help adjust my PDFMiner/Pytesseract-ocr to accommodate TempFile.

I tried switching UploadFile to bytes class, also tried using filename (but since its TempFile it is not saved and I guess there isnt a path)

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74165295/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886990/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804),  as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766160/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804).

Comment: `extract_text(pdf.file)` This function is called `extract_text()`. Doesn't that mean it will just call itself forever and forever? `except: pass` Don't do this. Ignoring exceptions means that your program will be harder to debug. The exception is there to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: thank you, Chris. Found my answer there! Although it wasn't the Pandas DF one. Also thank you, Nick, I'll keep that in mind!