# How to convert an AudioSegment into a bytes-like object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, bunnycdn

I'm using BunnyCDN to store some files, and it's required to store the audio as a binary file

```
# TODO: Upload the merged audio to the cloud storage: `merged_audio_path`
access_key = "*************-4bfe"
storage_zone_name = "***********-audios"
region = "uk"
merged_audio_bytes = merged_audio.raw_data
response = upload_file(access_key, storage_zone_name, region, merged_audio, "generic_name")
```

here is what I have done .

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766160/17865804) answer your question? Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) as well