# Any way to Librosa.load an audio file from a url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I am trying to use Librosa to load an audio from a url and my current solution is to just download the file then open it. I want to be able to run the program on a cloud service with no local storage but I would need a way to load from the url directly. I have looked around but cannot find anything.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426275/download-and-open-file-with-librosa-without-writing-to-filesystem) might be relevant.

Comment: What have you looked at, and why do those things not suit your use case? Please edit your post to contain these details.

Comment: Which cloud services for Python has no local storage?